# why oracle session blocking in such case

Tags: oracle, session, jdbc, prepared-statement

```
try{
   PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("delete from table_1 where key =123"));
   ps.execute();
   ps = conn.prepareStatement("delete from table_2 where key =123"));
   ps.execute();
}catch(Exception e){
  ......
}finally{
   ps.close();
   conn.close();

}
```

My code has a problem that I actually use 2 prepared statement but only close the last one, while running my code in production, there is a potential chance that oracle db session was blocking, anyone can tell me why no closed Preparedstatement will cause db session blocking? I did call conneciton close, and there is no exception while session blocking..

Comment: no closed-->not closed

Comment: From google, not close preparedStatement will cause cursor leak, anyone tell me cursor leak will lead to oracle session blocking?

Comment: You want to avoid cursor leaks; you'll run out of cursors. But what makes you think the session is blocked?

Comment: session blocking issue only occurs after we only added following code
ps = conn.prepareStatement("delete from table_2 where key =123"));
ps.execute();

Comment: What does it mean "session is blocking"? Your app hangs?. Do you have foreign keys in your tables?

Comment: yes, one thread hangs, no foreign keys

Answer (score 2):

Do you have autocommit enabled? In case not, there the first execution is waiting for a transaction command. It is always a good practice when using a prepared statement only for one transaction.

```
try{
   PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("delete from table_1 where key =123"));
   ps.execute();
   // autocommit enabled? -> conn.commit(); or only at the end of both executions (*1)- if there is a need

   PreparedStatement ps2 = conn.prepareStatement("delete from table_2 where key =123"));
   ps2.execute();
   // autocommit enabled? -> conn.commit(); (*1) commits both (ps/ps2)

} catch(Exception e){
    // rollback needed?
    conn.rollback();
} finally{
   // or commit here.. but be aware of your transaction needs for both ps
   closeStatement (ps);
   closeStatement (ps2);
   conn.close();
}

void closeStatement (PreparedStatement ps) {
  try {
    ps.close();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    <<log something or others>> 
  }
}
```